# Text slideshow stacking on top of each other for first 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slideshow

my text slideshow stacks on top of each other for a few seconds before finally working correctly. 
Here's what it looks like:
[Stacked text slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQQKo.png)
What can I do to fix that? Here's the code for the text:

```
            <div id="textslider"> 

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('testimony1'); ?> 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('testimony2'); ?> 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <p style="position: relative; left: -50%; border: none;"> 
                    <?php echo get_field('testimony3'); ?> 
                </p>

            </div>

            </div>
```

And here's the code for the slider in jQuery:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script>

$('#textslider > div:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() { 
$('#textslider > div:first').fadeOut(500)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#textslider');
},  3000);

      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#textslider > div:gt(0)').hide();` gets executed only after jQuery is loaded. You can simple move this to css by setting display property to none for all `#textslider` children except first one like this:

```
#textslider div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

See [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqjGyd).

Comment: Thank you @KrisD.  I used the code in your example to the "T" and the CSS code works just fine (No more stacked texts, only the first text shows up). However, the slideshow no longer works. I put the code in header.php. The slideshow elements are in content.php. Do you think that's the problem? Previously, the jQuery code only works (correctly, but with stacked texts), when put in header.php (not content.php)

Comment: you need to make sure that you load jQuery library for the code to get executed

Comment: Goodness... It suddenly just worked for no reason other than modding and re-saving the php file twice. Thank you so much. You are awesome!!